# send parameter to controller vueJS and laravel 8

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-8

I´m traying to send parameter to my controller with funcion vueJS, but i can´t get it... I´m noob in vueJS.

in my component i have this:

```
cargar(url = this.url, options = this.tableProps){
                axios.get(url, { opciones: options })
                        .then((response) => {
                            //console.log(options);
                            this.data = response.data;
                            console.log(response);
                        })
                        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
            },
            reloadTable(tableProps) {
                this.cargar(this.url, tableProps);
            
            }
```

`opciones` contain for first:

```
tableProps: {
                    search: '',
                    length: 100,
                    column: 'id',
                    dir: 'asc'
                },
```

and i want to send parameter to my controller, and if i change my datatabñe also.

In my controller i have this:

```
public function getAllUsers(Request $request){
        
        //$column = ;
        print_r($request->get('opciones'));

        exit();
        return response()->json(User::paginate(10));
    }
```

i´m traying to get parameter al show in console... for this i have exit.

but in my webroser console in tab networks it´s empty and in my console:

[image]

i can show opciones, but it´s in config...

Thanks so much for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to access the parameter like this `$request->opciones` instead of using `$request->get('opciones');`

To print the response back to console the correct way, you should do

```
console.log(response.data);
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but return me the same